# Compile a pspicture under Emacs

Tags: diagrams, pstricks, emacs, pst-tree

I copied the solution from this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43630/5110) to a file `try.tex` under `Emacs`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-tree}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem
ipsum. 

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{pspicture}(5,-5)
   \psgrid
   \pstree{\Tcircle{ }}
         {
           \pstree{\Tr{ }}{\Tfan}
           \pstree{\Tr{ }}{\Tfan}
         }
   \end{pspicture}
   \caption{}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. 

\end{document}
```

Then I try to compile it with `C-c C-c` which is `LaTeX`, but it returns to me `ERROR: Undefined control sequence.` at the place of `\pstree`. Could anyone tell me how to compile and preview this picture from Emacs?

Comment: That doesn't look like an Emacs problem, I think the problem is in the pst-tree macros.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the question in the related list that come up automatically: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10549/pstree-creates-confusing-undefined-control-sequence?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only sort-of an Emacs issue. As David Carlisle points out, you can't compile your example with pdflatex, you need regular latex. The fact that you don't get regular latex by default with Emacs suggests that you've enabled `TeX-PDF-mode`. You can turn that off again with `M-x TeX-PDF-mode`, and then compile as usual with `C-c C-c`.

Comment: You can also add a local variables line to your `.tex` file. Add the following at the top: `%-*- mode: latex; TeX-master: t; TeX-engine: latex -*-`. Here's the relevant section of the GNU Emacs manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html

Comment: @kahen: I think `TeX-PDF-mode` will override the `TeX-engine` local variable, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @Tyler: Well. Nothing's stopping you from putting `TeX-PDF-mode: nil` in the variables line as well

Comment: @kahen: good point!

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly unrelated to the editor you use.
You don't show the exact error you got but I would guess it is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 

l.13    \pstree
               {\Tcircle{ }}
```

which means that you have used pdflatex which doesn't work for pstricks, you need to use latex then dvips then ps2pdf.

This seems to be a duplicate but I'm using answer rather than comment to format the answer,
Your example works for me with latex. no need to vote for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your file compile just fine on my TeXLive2020/Debian box. AUCTeX-12.2.4/Emacs-26-3
I just add \usepackage{pstricks} and some file variables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-tree}

\begin{document}
 Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem
 ipsum. 

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(5,-5)
   
  \psgrid
  \pstree{\Tcircle{ }}
     {
       \pstree{\Tr{ }}{\Tfan}
       \pstree{\Tr{ }}{\Tfan}
     }
   \end{pspicture}
   \caption{}
  \end{figure}

  Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. 

  \end{document}:

 % Local Variables:
 % TeX-PDF-from-DVI: "Dvips"
 % TeX-PDF-mode: 1
 % End:
```